# Can I attach a small spinning reel to a baitcasting rod?

Tags: gear, fishing, diy

I have an idea to attach a small spinning reel abu silver max 5, to an ugly stik 7'6" medium light casting reel (which I already own), to fish sub 10 gram lures and live bait.  Anyone see a major problem with this? (I am trying to save the expense of buying a dedicated spinning rod, since I already own the baitcasting rod.

Comment: A lighter rod would probably throw the lure a bit further, but it won't hurt to give it a go.  You may want to go for heavier than you would with a light rod.  Give it a go - a lure in the water will catch many more fish than one in its case.

Answer (score 2):

Typically as far as spinning/casting goes, not very good to mix the two. I would go to Walmart and buy a $20 spinning rod. The eyelits are extremely different and trying to use the wrong style reel usually doesn't pan out very well.

Comment: Also, the spines of the two rod types are in different positions.